# Insert Concurrently in jpa

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency

I am working on a project where we have to insert record into a table concurrently.

example if 2 instances are inserting the data into a table then the execution should be concurrent. I want both the records to be inserted into the database.

Below is the entity class

```
@Entity
public class Department {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  @Version
  private long version;
  private Integer address
  private String name;
   
}
```

Below is the Executor service

```
public class EmployeeUpdateWithoutForceIncrement {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
     
          
          es.execute(() -> {
              saveEmployee();
          });
          es.execute(() -> {
             saveEmployee();
          });
          es.shutdown();
          es.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      } 
}
```

I have not added the static main class here in order to keep it short

```
saveEmployee(){
        List<Employee> elist=rpo.findAll();
        Employee e=elist.get(el.size()-1);
        e.setAddress(e.getAddress()+1);
        repo.save(e);
        }
```

**Excepted Output**

```
    id  name  Address
    1   test    1
    2   test2   2
    3   test2   3
```

**Actual Output**

```
id  name  Address
1   test    1
2   test2   2
3   test2   2
```

How can I make this work. I want both the record to be inserted with incremental address.
Address should be max value of previous record stored in the db

Comment: I can not understand what you want to do and why do you not using repo.save?

Comment: @VJR the executor service is called twice right so I want 2 records to be inserted. Now one record is inserted, for the second one I get duplicate key exception

Comment: @VJR The question is about concurrent insertion and not about jpa save method!. I have updated my question removing  the custom insert for the sake of simplicity

Comment: Please read https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-version-property-hibernate/ (esp. the (NOT) "Changing the entity version" part;)

Answer (score 0):

@Version annotation is making the version header values lockup and generating the same values. Here is the use case of [@Version](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Version.html#:%7E:text=Annotation%20Type%20Version&text=This%20annotation%20specifies%20the%20version,and%20for%20optimistic%20concurrency%20control.) annotation. Try making it a serial generated value.